# Python, Django: catch SMTPRecipientsRefused. Get "undefined variable" instead

Tags: python, django, exception, smtp

I get the following exception when I try to send an email:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  my_own_functions ...
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\mail\message.py", line 248, in send
    return self.get_connection(fail_silently).send_messages([self])
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\mail\backends\smtp.py", line 92, in send_messages
    sent = self._send(message)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\mail\backends\smtp.py", line 110, in _send
    email_message.message().as_string())
  File "C:\Python27\lib\smtplib.py", line 733, in sendmail
    raise SMTPRecipientsRefused(senderrs)
SMTPRecipientsRefused: {'aaa': (553, "5.1.2 We weren't able to find the recipient domain. Please check for any\n5.1.2 spelling errors, and make sure you didn't enter any spaces, periods,\n5.1.2 or other punctuation after the recipient's email address. q10sm6381464wie.2")}
```

I want to catch that exception and have tried:

```
try:
    sendActivationEmail()
except SMTPRecipientsRefused:
    return "error"
```

However, that gives me an "undefined variable" error. It's not recognizing SMTPRecipientsRefused. In Eclipse it says "Undefined variable: SMTPRecipientsRefused"

Comment: Please paste the exact error message and stack trace

Comment: Ok, so you're raising and catching the right error.  Please paste the code in your exception handler.

Comment: change `except SMTPRecipeintsRefused` to `except smtplib.RecipientsRefused`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An exception is just like any other class in Python: you need to import it into your code before you can reference it. You need `from smtplib import SMTPRecipientsRefused`.

Comment: or just `smtplib.RecipientsRefused`

Comment: Nice, thanks, solved it. Although just smtplib.RecipientsRefused did not work (maybe because I don't import smtlib)

Comment: I was able to use `smtplib.SMTPRecipientsRefused` after importing smtplib